# Pruning a Simplicity case expression

Tags: simplicity

I am trying to spend from a branched Simplicity program, but I don't wanna supply the signatures in the untaken branch, so I am trying to prune the program by hand. I have verified that I can take the `commitmentRoot` of a checkSig with the signature set to `undefined`.

To make a valid spend, I think I need to construct a pruned program that has the same `CommitmentRoot` that the full program has. So I boiled by program down to a single case expression:

```
u :: CommitmentRoot () ()
u = unit

full :: CommitmentRoot (Bit, ()) ()
full = cond u unit

pruned :: CommitmentRoot (Bit, ()) ()
pruned = assertr (commitmentRoot u) unit
```

But the `CommitmentRoot`s do not have the same hash:

```
*Main> (encode.fromShort.hash256.commitmentRoot) pruned
"7b4082aaae5e289f29855ede047b2b6598805b153324aa3a5fd4fec5b1a86053"
*Main> (encode.fromShort.hash256.commitmentRoot) full
"dded2b0938bb9f58f20324ab1f699e7006ffd8e9251b3ddd0f551de1d66fe119"
```

What gives? Is my understanding that I need a matching `CommitmentRoot` incorrect? If it is not correct, how do I prune a case expression correctly?

Furthermore, section "4.3.2.1 Pruning Unused case Branches" of the Simplicity Technical Report claims that "We can effectively replace any unused branch in a case expression with its commitment Merkle root." But if I do that, I cannot run the Simplicity program with `runKleisli`. So how is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `cond` is

```
cond thn els = match (drop els) (drop thn)
```

Expanding this in your definition of `full` yields

```
full = match (drop unit) (drop u)
```

The correct pruned version should be

```
pruned = assertl (drop unit) (commitmentRoot (drop u))
```

which has commitment root that matches:

```
let full = cond unit unit in (flip Numeric.showHex "".integerHash256.commitmentRoot) (full :: CommitmentRoot (Bit, ()) ())
"dded2b0938bb9f58f20324ab1f699e7006ffd8e9251b3ddd0f551de1d66fe119"

let pruned = assertl (Simplicity.Term.Core.drop unit) (commitmentRoot (Simplicity.Term.Core.drop unit :: CommitmentRoot ((),()) ())) in (flip Numeric.showHex "".integerHash256.commitmentRoot) (pruned :: CommitmentRoot (Bit, ()) ())
"dded2b0938bb9f58f20324ab1f699e7006ffd8e9251b3ddd0f551de1d66fe119"
```

Better library support for pruning expressions is something that will be developed.